# How to check the tag contain text value and add attribute for text contain tag?

Tags: java, xml

I need to find the text inside the XML tag, it is also inside  Tag and I need to add an attribute name called Id for tag which contain Text. If that tag contain Id before creating and i need to avoid creating an attribute. Plaese refer my Java code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws TransformerException {

    String filePath = "/check/xmlNew.xml";
    File xmlFile = new File(filePath);
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
    try {
        dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
        addAttributeId(doc,root);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
                .newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(
                "/done/New_Attribute.xml"));
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        System.out.println("XML file updated successfully");
    } catch (SAXException | ParserConfigurationException | IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}




private static void addAttributeId(Document doc, Element root) {
    NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Element element = (Element) nodeList.item(i);
        System.out.println(element.getNodeName());

        NodeList nodeParent = doc.getElementsByTagName("parentTag");
        String parentTag = nodeParent.item(0).getAttributes()
                .getNamedItem("id").getNodeValue()
                + "_attr_";
        if(element.getNodeName().equals("#text")){
            Element rootNode = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagName(
                    element.getNodeName()).item(0);

            rootNode.setAttribute("id", parentTag + i);
             }
        }
      }

   }
```

```html
`<parentTag id="HD1235">
<responseDeclaration>
<correctResponse>
<value>QualityTest</value>
</correctResponse>
</responseDeclaration>
<item>
<sampleTest>
 <p>Who is president of uganda?</P>EX:<p id="HD1235_attr_0">Who is president of uganda?</P>
<span>
<object>Yoweri Museveni</object>
<span>
<object>
<p>Raúl Castro</p>ex:<p id="HD1235_attr_1">Raúl Castro</p>
</Object>
</span>
</sampleTest>
</item>
<score>
<p>Yingluck Shinawatra</p>
</score>
</parentTag> 
For Example:<p>Who is president of uganda?</P> This tag contain Text, So  for this tag i need to add new attribute ID.
OUTPUT Expected:<p id="HD1235_attr_0">Who is president of uganda?</P>
```

`

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be trying to do any of the things. It's not looking for text, or a tag that contains text. Where is the part that you wrote and that is trying to do these things? Or are you using some template code and trying to get us to write the rest for you.

Comment: StackOverflow is not here to write code for you. It's supposed to be a place where we help professional programmers with problems they encounter in their work. This means you are supposed to read documentation, learn about various XML parsers and their options, and try to build your own solution, and then we can help you with problems you encounter when you build your solution.